# Python's os.execvp equivalent for PHP

Tags: php, python, shell, command-line-interface

I've got a PHP command line program running. And I want to connect to a mysql shell straight from PHP. I've done this before in Python using os.execvp But I can't get the same thing to work in PHP.

I've tried the following functions:

- system
- passthru
- exec
- shell_exec

example:

```
system('mysql -u root -pxxxx db_name');
```

But they all seem to wait for mysql to exit and return something. What I really want is for PHP to launch the mysql shell and then exit it self. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want shell commands to be interactive, use:

```
system("mysql -uroot -p db_name > `tty`");
```

That will work for most cases, but will break if you aren't in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Give MySQL a script to run that's separate from the PHP script:

```
system('mysql -u root -pxxxx db_name < script.mysql');
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what acrosman said, you can also use the `-e` switch to pass SQL from the command line.

```
$sql = ".....";
system("mysql -u root -pxxxx db_name -e \"$sql\"");
```

Also, I hope your not actually connecting to the database as root from a PHP application.

Comment: Thankyou for the tip but it's not what I'm looking for. I want to move the user from the PHP cli into a mysql shell.